# Netty exceptions leading to DDos

Tags: netty

In netty framework if a exception is not handled correctly, would it leave to Ddos attack by creating threads and leaving them in running state?

Here is what I am facing:
One of the handlers in the pipeline throws exception. 
This is how `exceptionCaught` is implemented. 
It only logs the error on server. Do I need to do something to handle it correctly? 
Will this cause resource exhaustion?

```
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {    
      logger.error("Error in netty read/write: ", cause);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually what you want to do is to also close the `Channel` if you can not recover from the error. Its almost all the time a good idea to do this.

So add `ctx.close()` to the exceptionCaught method after logging.

Comment: In addition to closing the channel, is it needed to bubble the exception through the pipeline to the next handlers? Do I need to `fireCaughtException()`?

Comment: only if you want to do something in the next handler.